# Re-order custom post categories

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I am using the following code to retrieve categories from a custom post type:

```
<?php 
     $taxonomy = 'treatment';
     $terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
     if ( $terms && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :
?>

     <ul>

<?php foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>

                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term->slug, $taxonomy); ?>">
                        <h4><?php echo $term->name; ?></h4>
                    </a>
                </li>
<?php } ?>

        </ul>

<?php endif;?>
```

Now I want to be able to re-order these posts and have found a suitable plugin to do this. However, in order to make this work, I need to add 'orderby' => 'term_order' to the query.

Is this even possible with this loop? I have tried a loop like this within the above but it doesn't work. With the loop alone I cannot fetch the custom post categories:

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'treatments', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'orderby' => 'term_order' ) ); ?>

<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

    Content here

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this given code inside the loop.And please replace "custom_taxonomy_name" with your custom taxonomy name which you have registered for custom post type

```
    <?php $terms = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(),'custom_taxonomy_name' ); ?>
            <?php foreach( $terms as $term): ?><br>
                <span class="text-category">Category:<?php echo $term->name; ?></span>
            <?php endforeach;  ?>
```